# Is there a way to stop a keyword from appearing in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search, googlebot

I added a web site a while ago to Google's index and it contains lots of links with the text "Permalink" that, well, link to permalinks of different content/pages.

Now "Permalink" is the #1 keyword in Google Webmaster Tools.

Is there a way to prevent this?

#### EDIT:

It is possible to do this by replacing

```
<a href="url">Permalink</a>
```

With

```
<a href="url"></a>
```

And then using CSS to render the text Permalink:

```
a:after {
  content: 'Permalink';
}
```

But I was basically interested to know if it is possible to hint Google Bot to consider the term "Permalink" as insignificant.

Comment: Probably not :)

Answer (score 1):

The list of "Content Keywords" in Google Webmaster Tools is just a list of terms that are used on lots of pages on your site more frequently than other sites.    Your CSS trick would almost certainly remove the word from this list.

As far as I can tell, this list has little or no bearing on rankings.  Your site isn't ranking for "permalink" because you are not using it in your page titles and you don't have other sites talking about your site as being authoritative for "permalinks".

Similarly, moving other relevant terms for which you are trying to rank up this list doesn't seem to help them rank: I've tried.   I've found ways to use my main keywords on more pages on my site.  It did move them up this list in a straightforward manner, but it didn't improve rankings for phrases that included those words.

I now regard this report as a curiosity.  It is interesting to know what words you use on lots of pages on your site, but it isn't something to worry much about if some of the words are "wrong".